# C appending to array of struct

Tags: c, function

So from my understanding of C, if you want to change something permanently inside a function, you have to pass a pointer as an argument. However, I have this bit of code which appends to an array of structs without any pointers.

in some other file:

```
extern struct data *information;
```

in another file:

```
struct data *information
```

in some function:

```
information = malloc(sizeof(data));
```

finally the function in question:

```
void function(int total, bool status){

        total++;
        char input[30];

        printf("Please enter some input...\n>>>");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", input);

        //reallocate memory to fit new element
        information = realloc(information,sizeof(struct some_struct)*total); 


        //assign values to struct members
        strcpy(information[total-1].description,input);
        information[total-1].amount = total;


        return;
}
```

I tested this function by adding some example and when printing it was there. Is my understanding of this wrong, or is this meant to happen?

Comment: I have remove some of the code that isn't necessary for this question, that's why it seem status isn't used.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `input` is locale... what is `information` ?

Comment: You're using globals and forgetting to mention it.

Comment: @Stargateur ah yes I forgot to mention that information is an array of structs, I will edit the question now

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll edit it now

Comment: @OldProgrammer what needs to change? I have added a few updates but what else?

Comment: "information is a global array of struct " - then show the declaration.  People here are not mind readers.

Comment: What you tried to print? How you called the function? How you declared information? Without posting the minimal example, how it is possible to analyze your problem?

Comment: *"information is an array of structs"* - not possible. Native arrays cannot be the target of assignment. At best it is a pointer to a dynamic sequence of `struct some_struct`.

Comment: Think people are more focused on fixing the question rather than answering the question. It's a generic question. Am I supposed to pass the array of struct into the function to change it or is it fine to append like this

Comment: If the function expands the dynamic sequence, it needs the original pointer and the new size. How you get that back to the caller-side is up to you (pointer-to-pointer out parameter, function return result, or (please don't do this) a global, are all options). you'l need to update the size anyway, so I'd use the first (everything passed as in/out arguments) and use the return value as error-status.

Comment: @L2C: what is your problem in posting the complete code? How one can answer your question when you haven't given complete information about your problem. Did you post what you tried to print? How you declared information? Technology is not so much advanced that one can see code in your laptop and understand your problem.

Comment: @kadina not so much the problem of posting the code. I want to be able to apply it to all situations. Is that a problem? Or should I post the code and ask you to change it, only for you to reply this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @L2C: Don't think everyone is same. Some will say that it is not code wiring service. Not every one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `information` isn't declared inside of the function but you are able to access it.  That means it's declared as a global variable and is accessible from anywhere inside of your source file.

Had you declared this variable inside of a function, then you would need to pass its address into the function in order to modify it.

Comment: So as long as the array of struct is declared global I can make any modifications (add/delete/update) to it and it is permanent is what you're saying?

Answer (score 1):

Global variable means it is available to all the functions without passing to the functions. No need to pass the global variables. So the variables won't be on the function's local stack. So the global variable (in your case information) is able to retain the modified value through function calls.